# Case-Sensitive Column names not working with fluentd-plugin-sql and oracle-enhanced adapter

Tags: ruby, activerecord, oracle11g, fluentd, fluent-docker

In my `fluentd` config I have provided the following column_mapping:

```
<table login.*&gt;<br/>
        table 'login'
        column_mapping 'id:id,name:name,email:email,timestmp:timestmp' 
</table>
```

All the column names mentioned above are Case-Sensitive. But during the actual data insertion it gives an error.
The error message is:

> 2021-11-20 12:53:03 +0000 [warn]: #0 Failed to create the model.Ignore a record: error_class=ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError error="unknown attribute 'id' for Fluent::Plugin::SQLOutput::BaseModel_1361409501::Login." table="login" record="{"id":"febf2563-f5e9-4334-a412-6e25082a44ea","name":"testuser","email":"testuser@asd.com","timestmp":1637412777396}"

But the same operation is working when using `fluentd` with MySQL Configurations.

Comment: Is there in fact an `id` column in your DB?

Comment: Yes the table had id column, it is of type varchar.